# Función de Correlación en R

Tags: r

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño código en R que me devuelva la correlación entre dos variables según una condición.

En este caso tenemos un conjunto de archivos csv, la función pide el directorio donde están los archivos csv y un threshold. La función solo calculará los valores de correlación para los archivos csv que superen el threshold.

```
## función que calcula la correlación entre sulfato y nitrato
## El threshold determina el numero de casos completos
## Para calcular la correlación se deben de tener más casos completos
## Que el threshold

corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {

  ## accedemos a los archivos
  path <- paste0(getwd(), "/", directory)
  csv_file <- list.files(path, full.names = TRUE)
  # En vez de directorio podemos definir el path

  ## Creamos el vector vacio donde vamos a almacenar las correlacioens
  z <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 0)

  ## Accedemos a los archivos
  for (i in 1:length(csv_file)) {

    x <- read.csv(csv_file[i])

    if (sum(complete.cases(x)) > threshold) {

      ## Seleccionamos los sulfatos sin NA
      xSulfate <- x[which(!is.na(x$sulfate)), ]

      # De xSulfate seleccionamos las columnas sin NA de nitrates
      xPollutant <- xSulfate[which(!is.na(xSulfate$nitrate)), ]

      z <- c(z, cor(xPollutant$sulfate, xPollutant$nitrate))
    }
  }
  z
}
```

Al probar la función recibo este warning: 
 ***Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names***

En los archivos csv solamente hay tres columnas con valores para nitrato, sulfato y un ID. Por lo tanto, ¿dónde puede estar el problema?

Os adjunto un ejemplo de la forma que tienen los archivos csv. Son todos iguales.

[image: [1]]

Muchas gracias de antemano,
Un saludo,

Comment: Sin ver el archivo es difícil, pero el error es claro, en alguna fila tienes más columnas  de las que estás esperando, una posible fuente de problemas son las cadenas compuestas, es decir aquellas donde aparece el delimitador pero como parte de la cadena y no como separador.

Answer (score 2):

Tus datos numéricos del csv deben tener cifras decimales en formato español (con coma) y read.csv las entiende como separadores de campos. Si como imagino, el csv viene de una hoja de calculo XLSx en español, debes usar `read.csv2()` o editar los datos.